# Setting up a wordpress site using two different database

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I will try my best to describe the whole scenario as clearly as possible.

**Wordpress site 1**
Website name: Seller portal
Database: db1

**Wordpress site 2**
Website name: Customer portal
Database: db2

Both sites are made with *(wordpress + woocommerce)*. Both db1 and db2 are hosted on the same server.
On site 1, as a merchant you can publish new products for sale and you can also view your sales report. Let's say, on db1, table a,b,c,d,e are used to host your product information and sales report.

As mentioned before, site 2 running on database db2. But only for the product and sales section, it directly communicates with db1 (table a,b,c,d,e).

Therefore, site 1 and 2 store their user info, theme info everything on different databases. But when it comes to product and sales section, they share the same database. So, when anyone buys anything on site 2, merchants instantly gets the sales info on site 1. And when merchant publishes a new product to sale on site 1, users of site 2 will instantly see that new product on site 2.

Can anyone directs me to the right path how to achieve this? From wp-config files I see option to connect to only one database.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since the two sites are essentially the same instance, what is the purpose of having two separate databases?

If I had to use something like that I would try [creating a network](https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network). It is pretty easy to set up and you end up with basically what you are describing, two different sites that run on the same data, but with only one database.

The only problem is that if you decide to try it you will have to handle the merging of the two databases yourself.

Comment: I cannot use wp multisite because the project is to host the two sites on two different domains and the users of two sites must not share the same database table. But in multisite, for all the sites you need just one account to login.